# Copy folder with symlinks

Tags: symlink, file-copy

How can I copy a folder that contains symlinks and retain the symlinks in the destination folder? I'm doing something like this with PHP/Bash:

```
system("cp -r production-clone-target production-sites/{$instanceName}");
```

but the symlinks do not appear in the destination folder.

Comment: On BSD: `cp -PR source destination`.  On Linux: `cp -dr source destination`.  However, with PHP there are probably much better approaches than running `system()` (why do you have `system()` enabled, in the first place?).

Comment: You mean from a security standpoint?

Comment: I'd bet many things that the answer is yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19356365) seems to be a far more reasonable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `--preserve=links` switch to your `cp` command.

From `man cp`:

```
    --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), 
if possible additional attributes: context, links,xattr, all
```

Edit: If under OS X; use `cp -a`.

Comment: Assuming Linux FTW.

Comment: @SatoKatsura True, fixed!

Comment: On OpenBSD: "cp: unknown option -- a"

Comment: @SatoKatsura Huh! Didn't know that, thanks for the info, just tested under OS X, where the `-a` switch works. Thought it was the same for all BSD's.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also rsync:

```
-l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
```

I like `-a`, which also includes this one, to copy also sub-directories etc.

```
-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

So, in your code example you could do this:

```
system("rsync -a production-clone-target production-sites/{$instanceName}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the valid concerns about using `system()` in your PHP program:

`cp` may not have standardized options for doing this that are common to Linux and the BSDs, but `pax` has.

```
( cd source && pax -p p -r -w * destination/ )
```